# Check for strict sublist

Tags: python

Is there any way to check for strict sublist:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [1,3]
c = [1,2,3,4]
```

Given those lists, I want to achieve something like this:

```
>> a.is_strict_sublist(c)
True

>> b.is_strict_sublist(c)
False
```

`Update:`

I rephrase my question:

This is what I wanted to do. I am traversing a graph, where I have several paths (list of nodes). Unfortunately, I find duplicates and sub-lists. Is there any better way to remove sub-lists other than using `issubset`

In the above example, I want only 2 paths: `[1,3]` and `[1,2,3,4]`

Comment: Look at the documentation, you almost got it: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set.issubset

Comment: Why should the second example return `False`? Clearly it should be `True`??

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> a = {1, 2, 3}
>>> b = {1, 2, 3}
>>> c = {1, 3}
>>> b <= a # is subset
True
>>> b < a # is strict subset
False
>>> c < a
True
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, you can use the [`set.issubset`](https://devdocs.io/python~2.7/library/stdtypes#set.issubset) call:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = [1,3]
>>> c = [1,2,3,4]
>>> set(a).issubset(b)
False
>>> set(a).issubset(c)
True
>>> set(b).issubset(c)
```

Alternatively, for a strict subset match, you can also use the *less than* operator:

```
>>> set(a) < set(c)
True
```